# why Navbar toggler is not working on vanilla js and css

Tags: javascript, html, css

When i click the mavbar toggler button, the toggler does not appear, it pops out immediately
i have seen this in youtube tutorial it was working fine for him but when i try it the toggler does not show, i don't know what the issue is and i checked the code also the code same
can anyone help to get rid of this issue
thanks in advance

```js
const toggleButton = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle-button')[0]
const navbarLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-links')[0]

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navbarLinks.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

```css
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #195794;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.brand-title {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  color: white;
}

.navbar-links ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar-links ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar-links ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 1.2rem;
  display: block;
}

.navbar-links ul li:hover {
  background-color: #1d64aa;
}

.toggle-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.3rem;
  right: 1rem;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 1.4rem;
}

.toggle-button .bar {
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@media(max-width:800px) {
  .toggle-button {
    display: flex;
  }
  .navbar-links {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
  .navbar-links ul {
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .navbar-links ul li {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navbar-links.active {
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="brand-title"> title</div>
  <a href="" class="toggle-button">
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
  </a>
  <div class="navbar-links">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your .toggle-button

```
<a href="" class="toggle-button">
  <span class="bar"></span>
  <span class="bar"></span>
  <span class="bar"></span>
</a>
```

Change it to div :

```
<div class="toggle-button">
  <span class="bar"></span>
  <span class="bar"></span>
  <span class="bar"></span>
</div>
```

Change your .toggle-button CSS:

```
.toggle-button:hover{
    cursor: pointer
}
```

Comment: I think using JS to preventDefault() the link behaviour as @Jakub told you is not a good practice. You should fix it by changing your HTML and CSS

Answer (score 3):

Problem is in the JS

You need to disable a link by

```
toggleButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
 navbarLinks.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

```js
const toggleButton  = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle-button')[0]
const navbarLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-links')[0]

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
 navbarLinks.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

```css
 .navbar{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
   align-items: center;
   background-color: #195794;
   padding: 0 !important;
   
 }
 .brand-title{
   font-size: 1.5rem;
   margin: 1rem;
   color: white;
 }
 .navbar-links ul{
   display: flex;
   margin: 0;
 }
 .navbar-links ul li{
   list-style: none;
 }
 .navbar-links ul li a{
   text-decoration: none;
   color: white;
   padding: 1.2rem;
   display: block;
 }
.navbar-links ul li:hover{
  background-color: #1d64aa;
}
.toggle-button{
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.3rem;
  right:1rem;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 1.4rem;
 }
 .toggle-button .bar{
   height:3px;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: white;
   border-radius: 10px;
 }

@media(max-width:800px){
 .toggle-button{
   display: flex;
 }
 .navbar-links{
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
 } 

 .navbar{
   flex-direction: column;
   align-items: flex-start;

 }
 .navbar-links ul{
   width: 100%;
   flex-direction: column;
 }
 .navbar-links ul li{
   text-align: center;
 }

 .navbar-links.active{
   display: flex;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Document</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="Site.css">
  </head>
<body>
 <nav class="navbar">
     <div class="brand-title"> title</div>
     <a href="" class="toggle-button">
         <span class="bar"></span>
         <span class="bar"></span>
         <span class="bar"></span>
     </a>
         <div class="navbar-links">
             <ul>
                 <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                 <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                 <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                 
             </ul>
         </div>
 </nav>
 <script src="Site.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```